# Wait for axios response before doing anything else

Tags: javascript, laravel-mix

I have the following function in my `app.js`:

```js
window.SGN = require('./core/core');

SGN.importPermissions();
```

which comes from a home made package:

```js
define('SGN',
  ['axios'],
  function (axios) {
    var SGN = {
      importPermissions: () => {
        axios
          .get(`/admin/users/permissions`)
          .then((response) => {
            window.SGN.permissions = Object.values(response.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          })
          .then(() => {
          });
      }
    }
    return SGN;
  }
);
```

However sometimes the rest of the application is run before that `axios` request is finished, how can I make it so that the application always waits for the request before everything else?

---

Although this looks like a duplicate question, I haven't found any answer that fixes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest of the application should get informed about when the asynchronous request has completed. For that to happen you should *return* the promise that you have created:

```
var SGN = {
  importPermissions: () => {
    return axios
//  ^^^^^^
      .get(`/admin/users/permissions`)
      // ...etc
```

The rest of the application should be made dependent on the promise returned by `SGN.importPermissions()`, and so it could be like this:

```
SGN.importPermissions().then(() => {
    // Anything that depends on the request should execute here,
    // or be called from here
});
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't do it, as this is a list of attributes that gets checked against through the application and I can't just put inside the `then(() => {})` so the problem still persists.

Comment: You will have to do that. You cannot expect the rest of the application to get *future* information *now*. So you have to fix the design of your application.

Comment: Sadly I cannot do that. I need to find a way to completely halt all loading until that request ends, then the application can resume loading.

Comment: No, you should not completely halt all loading. That is an antipattern. Embrace asynchrony. Everything is possible with it.